# limit of ratio of left sided limit to limit of poisson CDF

Tags: probability, limits

I am trying to show that :
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\overline{F}(x-)}{\overline{F}(x)} \neq 1
$$
for the poisson$(\lambda)$ distribution. I'm not sure where I am going wrong:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1- e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}}{1- e^{-\lambda }\sum_{i=0}^x\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}} \quad x\in \{1,2,... \}
$$
then taking the limit of the sums, makes them both infinite sums, and this results in the limit being $0/0$. Is there anything wrong with this reasoning?

**update**: The limit may be written as:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-\sum_{i=0}^{x-1} \frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}}{1-\sum_{i=0}^{x} \frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=x}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}}{\sum_{i=x+1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^ie^{-\lambda}}{i!}}\\
&=1+\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{x+i}}{(x+i)!}}\\
&=1+\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x!\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{i}}{(x+i)!}}\\
\end{align*}

Expanding the denominator:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x! \bigg(\frac{1}{x!} + \frac{\lambda}{(x+1)!} +\frac{\lambda^2}{(x+2)!} + \dots \bigg)
$$
$$
=\lim_{x \to \infty} 1+ \frac{\lambda}{(x+1)} + \frac{\lambda^2}{(x+1)(x+2)} + \dots = 1
$$

Therefore:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\overline{F}(x-)}{\overline{F}(x)} =2 \neq 1
$$

Comment: But the limit of this ratio **is** 0/0... so all you have to do is to study the limit of $$\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x/x!}{\sum\limits_{i\geqslant x}e^{-\lambda}\lambda^i/i!},$$ which is the inverse of $$x!\sum_{i\geqslant 0}\lambda^i/(i+x)!.$$ Any idea?

Comment: just a note: $1- e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}=1-F(x-1)$ not $F(x-1)$.

Comment: ... and how are $x$ and $y$ related?

Comment: @Math-fun sorry, it was a typo, meant to be the converse of the cdf

Comment: @Did the limit of that as x goes to $\infty$ is just 1? Since they are both going at the same rate, i get that the final answer for the limit is zero

Comment: The $y$-for-$x$ typos remain.

Comment: @dimebucker91 This has to be proven. The considerations in your comment are not a proof.

Comment: @Did is it a typo? I thought that maybe since the notation $F(y-) = \lim_{y \to x^-}$ so wasn't sure if the question had it wrong

Comment: Definitely a typo. Note that $F(y-)$ would be $\lim\limits_{z\to y-}F(z)$, not what you write.

Comment: @Did After expanding the sum and then taking the limit of x, i get that the result should be $\lambda$, so that the limit in the question should be $1-1/\lambda$

Comment: I disagree. You might want to show your workings in detail (note that, to avoid these lengthy exchanges in comments, these tries should have been explained, from the start, in the question itself).

Comment: @Did Sorry about that, I've updated now to include full working, thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: The first $1-\lim$ is wrong: should read $1+$ something, and the sum in the denominator does not start as you write it does.

Comment: @Did Not quite sure which part of the expansion is wrong for the denominator?

Comment: Your denominator is currently the sum starting at $i=x$ while you want the sum starting at $i=x+1$.